# Flex SEO & Google

Tags: apache-flex, seo

I wrote a trivia game in Flex (flash). The site is written entirely in Flex. Almost all of the text is pulled from a database. It also has a fair number of images. The image file paths are pulled from the db.

My site's not getting any hits. If I check on google site:mysite it the url appears only. I know that inbound links are important and I'll try to get some. At the moment, I don't have any inbound links. In google webmaster tools, if I look under the site's keywords, there are 0. My sites been up for about a month.

Any suggestions on how to improve this situation?

(I've seen a few people ask for help with Flash SEO and the comments tended to be of the "don't use Flash" variety-- which aren't too helpful if you've written something in Flex/Flash).

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article: [Read Here](http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/seo-friendly-flash.shtml)

> SEO FLASH PROGRAMMING
>
> My recommended Flash SEO method uses a
> DIV with search-engine-accessible,
> primary content, and an open source
> Javascript function called swfobject()
> to detect when browsers are capable of
> viewing Flash. When an appropriate
> version of Flash player is present,
> the Javascript manipulates the page's
> document object model (DOM) to replace
> the primary content with the Flash
> movie. Most search engine spiders
> can't handle Flash, so they will elect
> to view the primary content. The
> primary content may contain links,
> headings, styled text, images—anything
> we can add to an ordinary HTML page.
> With SEO copyediting and coding skills
> applied to the primary content, Flash
> becomes a non-issue.
>
> Flash accessibility programming isn't
> spamming, as long as the primary
> content and the visible movie are
> essentially the same. The World Wide
> Web Consortium (W3C) Web Accessibility
> Initiative (WAI) specifically states
> that multimedia content should have an
> alternative representation available.
> Accessibility programming creates the
> benefit of presenting visual
> information without losing the
> visitors and search engines who depend
> upon textual content.
>
> As of July 2007, I discussed this
> method with Dan Crow of Google. He
> warned that this programming method
> could draw attention because of the
> possibility for abuse. If you use this
> method, make sure the alternative
> content is a faithful representation
> of the Flash content, and avoid
> combining this with other coding
> methods that could be abused. While
> this SEO method is not abusive, it is
> aggressive because there is a small
> risk that the search engines could
> mistakenly decide that the primary
> content is a form of cloaking.

I would also create a sitemap and link to multiple keyword rich landing pages about your game with a link back to the game. The more content google has to bite into the better changes someone will find you.

You also need to market your site...just because you build it doesn't mean they will come. Use twitter, facebook and any other form of social media to get the word out. You may also try buying a few bucks worth of ad words to start the ball rolling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to only the url appearing in Google is probably as simple as adding a meta description tag.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=79812

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/09/improve-snippets-with-meta-description.html

It would also probably be beneficial to provide a description or instructions for the trivia game in HTML alongside the Flex part of the website, if this is possible.